# osmdroid: Follow map north on rotation

Tags: java, osmdroid

I want to integrate OSM into my application to show the map of a given location. I want to show the north direction on the map, even when the user rotates the map. The OsmAnd app has a compass mode exactly like this, but the osmdroid API does not seem to have it.

**Relevant code**

```
public class MapFragment extends Fragment {
    FragmentMapBinding binding;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentMapBinding.inflate(inflater);

        Configuration.getInstance().load(getContext(), PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getContext()));

        binding.map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
        binding.map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

        CompassOverlay compassOverlay = new CompassOverlay(getContext(), new InternalCompassOrientationProvider(getContext()), binding.map);
        compassOverlay.enableCompass();
        binding.map.getOverlays().add(compassOverlay);

        RotationGestureOverlay rotationOverlay = new RotationGestureOverlay(binding.map);
        rotationOverlay.setEnabled(true);
        binding.map.getOverlays().add(rotationOverlay);

        return binding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        binding.map.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        binding.map.onPause();
    }
}
```

Is there any built in solution I miss, or I have to implement something on my own?

Answer (score 0):

Usage of CompassOverlay is shown in the sample app OpenStreetMapViewer:

https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/blob/master/OpenStreetMapViewer/src/main/java/org/osmdroid/samplefragments/location/CompassRoseSample.java

Comment: I have implemented my own solution with a custom drawable and a touch listener.